# Where is the JTAG header in this circuit?

Tags: microcontroller

[image]

Where is the JTAG header in this circuit? Is it the 7 pin or 10 pin socket?  It is a Texas Instrument MCU.

Comment: How about you look at the datasheet for the chip (s) in question?  Find the JTAG pins and use your multimeter to see which connector pins they go to.  Document what you find out - this will help further down the road.

Comment: It's an MSP430F2617 in TQFP64 package, good luck.

Comment: do you have information that leads you to believe that the JTAG connector is one of those two?

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what the PCB manufacturer did.

I've seen JTAG as 2x5 before, but I've also seen 2x10. It's odd that they want you to use JTAG but then they didn't put a keyed shroud around it.

For the less-than-friendly PCBs I've had to hookup flying leads.

If there's no end-user documentation, you're going to have to try to follow the traces from the IC in question. I don't think there's enough detail in this picture for us to help.

Comment: I have used continuity tester and found out that the 7 pins (single side) have all JTAG pins connected to it. The lowest 1st pin is Vcc, 2nd pin is TDI/TCLK, 3rd pin is TDO/TDI, 4th pin is TMS, 5th pin is TCK, 6th pin is Gnd, 7th pin is blank (top most).  Is there a USB to JPAG cable with this ordering? And why should the USB be connected to the Vcc and Ground? Won't the 4 JTAG pins be sufficient?

Comment: You need a JTAG cable with flying leads [similar to this](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Xilinx/HW-USB-FLYLEADS-G?qs=rrS6PyfT74fcsFrmxJq1qQ%3D%3D) like I had noted.

Comment: I bought an MSP-FET uif with 14 pin JTAG cable. The flying leads you mentioned above are not compatible with it. Do you know flying leads that could be used in the MSP-FET uif? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry my only experience with JTAG has been to program FPGAs so you use the manufacturer's dongle in either a standard config or with the leads like I noted, depending on how you laid out the PCB.